# BoxCutter Automatically Switches to View Surface Mode

Tags: modeling, add-on, hard-ops

I'm learning to use BoxCutter and when I Left Mouse Button click and drag, the Surface Mode is automatically changing to View (see screencast). How can I get BoxCutter to stay in Object Mode?

[image: Automatically Switching to View]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This video was provided by Team Csharp, the makers of Boxcutter. https://youtu.be/MxchEkYi940

The reason it's switching is because the drawing of the box is starting in the View rather than on the Object itself.